# UITextView won't scroll from outside particular area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView with approx 100 lines(for testing purpose its static) which scrolls fine but when i try to scroll from approx 150 its from the bottom i can not scroll. That means it lets me scroll from only certain area of the textview. for example see the image below. If i try to select and scroll above 3 line from top, i can scroll but below 3rd line, It won't let me scroll. I went through documentation but couldn't find anything that makes sense. [image]

Comment: Is there more text to be viewed at the bottom once you scroll up past the third line on the top? If not then you simply need to move your UITextView window up a bit.

Comment: There may be something intercepting your touch events in that area. Do you have *anything* other than the text view in that area, hidden or not?

Comment: David there are two views i am hiding. one view is collectionview strip and other is to show the semi-transparent background for collectionview strip. But that is only required for certain case.

Comment: But strangely even when those views are visible, two lines above that view dont respond to any gesture on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing the frame of your UITextView so it does not overlap the UITabBarView. If you create this in interface builder, you can resize it there.

Comment: Thanks Enrico for your answer. I figured it wasn't issue with the overlapping. The issue was the length of the superview of the textview. It was sized for landscape mode. after increasing the height of the superview, it scrolls fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if there is some area that is not taking ui touches, thAT means, your UITextView is being overlapped by another view. try:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textView];
```

also think about Enrico's answer.

Comment: Thanks Nikita. Issue got resolved by increasing the height of the superview. The length of the superview was good for landscape mode but not for portrait.

Answer (score 1):

Put Background color for TextView. It will give you extact idea of TextView Complete framing and is it sub view of background or foreground.